# Dash shell could not able to execute the given command with out double quotes

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, sh, dash-shell

I am facing a problem with some sample code in an Ubuntu environment with dash shell.

When the following block of code is executed in dash shell on Ubuntu Server OS, then I got the output as given below.

```
#!/bin/sh
cmd="ls"
arg=" -lt"
exec "$cmd $arg"
```

Output1 :

```
./test3.sh: 4: exec: ls  -lt: not found
```

But if I run the following modified code then I got the correct output as given below.

```
#!/bin/sh
cmd="ls"
arg=" -lt"
exec $cmd $arg
```

Output2 :

```
root@ubuntu:~/test# ./test3.sh total 6164
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      45 Dec 10 05:40 test3.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   35962 Dec 10 03:29 debug.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first version, the double quotes protect the space in the exec parameter from being interpreted by the shell, so `exec` sees a single word with a space in it, "ls -lt". There isn't a program of that name, so it fails. In the second version, the shell sees the space.

You don't need the space in the value of `arg`, because in the second version you have a space between `$cmd` and `$arg` anyway, but it doesn't do any harm. You don't actually need any quotes at all in this simple case, but if you are in the habit of including them, you won't forget them when you need them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Peter and i agree with you. I hard one more doubt related to using double quotes. If a string variable contains n or t character then I could not able to see these characters when I print them. But if I use double quotes then only I could able to print them in my devlelopment environment. But in sample script it is working properly.

Comment: Donovan's comment about this is correct. Not all shells will interpret backslash characters, but Dash is one that does.

Answer (score 1):

Your first exec is trying to find a command "ls -lt" (with the space included as part of the command name.  Whereas your second example (without the use of quotes), is running the command as you intended, with 'ls' being the command and '-lt' being an argument to that command.

Comment: Thanks Donovan for the help. I asked one more question when replying to Peters comment w.r.t n & t characters in shell variables. Could you please help on this also.

Comment: I think the answer to your second question lies in the fact that the shell interpolates variables within double-quotes.  So the special characater \n (newline) and \t (tab) are being interpreted before any output is displayed.  To print a literal \t or \n, you would need to use single-quotes, which the shell will not attempt interpolation on.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes I agree that we need to use escape sequence for printing \n or \t but in my case it is just normal n & t characters. But this happens only in my development environment where the script is a very big file. In a sample script everything is working fine. Not sure what settings are making it not to print n&t characters.